# Why does C++ allow a local variable in class member function to be the same name as a member variable?

Tags: c++, class

Why does C++ allow a local variable in class member function to be the same name as a member variable? What is the benefit of allowing this?

The following code compiles.

```
class test
{
public:
  int i = 4;
  void func(){
    int i = 5;

    cout << i << endl;
    cout << this->i << endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  test t;
  t.func(); 
}
```

The output is

```
5
4
```

I don't think there's any undefined behavior going on here so it seems the standard allows this.

I just spent an hour debugging a code where I accidentally used the following in a class member function

```
auto member_var_name = some_val;         // declared and defined a local variable with the same name as the class member variable
```

when I meant to just do

```
member_var = some_val;
```

I did know that constructors could use class member names as parameter names, but I didn't know something like this was allowed as well.

Comment: You can *shadow* variables in an inner scope if you want. C++ won't stop you.

Comment: What kind of answer do you want? This is simply how stuff works. As you noticed, name shadowing works everywhere else, so it makes sense that you can shadow member variables as well.

Comment: why should this be forbidden? It would annoy people who want to write code like that and have zero benefit for all others.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what is the benefit of allowing this

Comment: Edit the question with your question.

Comment: @idclev463035818 "Zero benefit for all others?" I mean I clearly could have benefited here.

Comment: what is not clear? `i` refers to `i` and `this->i` refers to the member

Comment: I agree: to avoid making these kind of errors, on gcc you can enable `-Wshadow`, which might help.

Comment: It isn't just C++, C# and Java are the same.  C# even has a naming convention which suggests you name properties the same as classes so you can end up with member declarations like "MyClass MyClass" where one is the class and the other is the property...

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't think we're on the same page. I said my example above clearly shows that I could have benefited from a standard that did not allow shadowing. I don't often use `this->` to refer to an instance's member variables.

Comment: That's why a lot of people prefix member names with `m`, or `m_`.

Comment: @geza The issue here is that I meant to have just assigned a member variable to some value, but I ended up defining a new local variable.

Comment: If you are using gcc, `-Wshadow -Werror` will make it illegal. Probably also possible in other compilers.

Comment: @cigien Ah great. I will try this in the future :). Does this work with Clang too?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Does this work with CLang too?

Comment: Why did you put `int` there, if it is supposed to be just an assignment? Was it a copy-paste?

Comment: @lamanon It seems so: https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wshadow. Remember though that `-Werror` raises all warnings to errors (which is something you should want usually)

Comment: @geza. I accidentally put `int` there.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen There is also `-Werror=shadow`  (for both, clang and gcc) that only turns one warning into errors